# Create button without background, border and with images for normal, reollver, pressed states

Tags: uwp-xaml

In UWP XAML app I need to create a button with 3 separate images for each of states: normal, rollover, pressed. I want to show just the image, without background and border (which exist by default).
I started with the following:

```
    <Button x:Name="BackButton" Click="On_Back_Button" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="60" Height="60" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0">
        <Image Source="Assets/close.png" 
                Width="60" 
                Height="60"/>
    </Button>
```

Now I want it to switch to `"Assets/close_hover.png"` when cursor points to it, and `"Assets/close_pressed.png"` when it's pressed. How do I do it?

Comment: Hello, if you want to achieve such an effect, then you need to modify the ControlTemplate of the Button. But Button only has four states of `Normal`, `PointerOver`, `Pressed` and `Disabled`, the rollover you mentioned is not among them. Does it correspond to the PointerOver state?

Comment: Yes, under "rollover" I meant `PointerOver`, thanks. Could you drop a hint how exactly I should modify ControlTemplate to specify custom images for `PointerOver` and `Pressed` states?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to modify the display of the Button in different states, then you need to create a Button `ControlTemplate`. By copying the default ControlTemplate, we can modify it to the following code:

```xml
<Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="ImageButtonStyle">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BackgroundSizing" Value="OuterBorderEdge" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForeground}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="{StaticResource UseSystemFocusVisuals}" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualMargin" Value="-3" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
          BackgroundSizing="{TemplateBinding BackgroundSizing}"
          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
          ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
          CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
          Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
          HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
          VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
          AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw">

                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Content">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/close_hover.png" 
                                                       Width="60" 
                                                       Height="60"/>       
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Content">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/close_pressed.png" 
                                                       Width="60" 
                                                       Height="60"/>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">

                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBackgroundDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonBorderBrushDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonForegroundDisabled}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>

                        </VisualStateGroup>

                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                </ContentPresenter>

            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You can put this code in the `App.Resources` tag, or you can create a `ResourceDictionary` and reference it in **App.xaml**. If you want to know more about resource references, you can check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/resourcedictionary-and-xaml-resource-references)

**Usage**

```xml
<Button x:Name="BackButton" Click="On_Back_Button" Width="60" Height="60"
        Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}">
    <Image Source="Assets/close.png" 
        Width="60" 
        Height="60"/>
</Button>
```